# Request validation: Get field name in messages.properties using MessageSource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc

I use a custom validation `MessageSource` as shown below in a Spring Boot app:

***MessageSourceConfig:***

```
@Configuration
public class MessageSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = 
            new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return bean;
    }
}
```

***RequestClass:***

```
public class LoginForm {

    @NotEmpty(message = "{email.notempty}")
    @Email
    private String email;

    @Size(min = 8, max = 50, message = "{password.size}")
    @NotNull
    private String password;
}
```

***messages.properties:***

```
email.notempty=email is not valid. Please provide valid email.
password.size=password size must be between 8 and 50.
```

I just want to get `field name` and some annotation parameters e.g. `min` / `max` and use them in my message. With the help of this, I can reduce the message definitions and re-use the same message with different parameters.

So, how can I do this? I tried something e.g. `{0}` in the messages, but did not work :(

Comment: Does anybody else have ever used messages.properties ? Or get field name while validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement custom validator class for your behaviour.
e.g.

Field annotation

```
@Target({ FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = StringSizeValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface SizeValid {

    long min() default 0;

    long max() default Long.MAX_VALUE;

    String fieldName() default "";

    String message() default "";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

Validator

```
public class StringSizeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<SizeValid, String> {

    private static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE = "Size of field %s should be between %s and %s";

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableListableBeanFactory factory;

    private long max;
    private long min;
    private String fieldName;
    private String message;

    @Override
    public void initialize(SizeValid constraintAnnotation) {
        this.max = constraintAnnotation.max();
        this.min = constraintAnnotation.min();
        this.fieldName = constraintAnnotation.fieldName();
        this.message = constraintAnnotation.message();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (value.length() >= min) {
            if (value.length() <= max) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        String formattedMessage;

        if (StringUtils.hasText(message)) {
            String messageStr = factory.resolveEmbeddedValue(message); //here we are trying to get message from props

            if (messageStr == null) {
                throw new UnknownFormatConversionException(String.format("Property %s not found", message));
            }

            formattedMessage = messageStr.formatted(min, max);
        } else {
            formattedMessage = DEFAULT_MESSAGE.formatted(fieldName, max, min);
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException(formattedMessage);
    }
}
```

Your dto

```
public class LoginForm {

    @NotEmpty(message = "${email.notempty}")
    @Email
    private String email;

    @SizeValid(min = 8, max = 50, message = "${password.size}")
    @NotNull
    private String password;

}
```

And then annotate your dto with `@Valid` annotation in controller method.

In another way you can create some Validatable interface with `validate()` method, implement this interface with dto, override `validate()` method by creating your custom exception instances, aggregate and return an array of this exceptions from `validate()`. On the next step create validator bean which should be triggered by some custom annotation on method argument. Validator should call interface `validate()` method. From the array of your exceptions it could choose proper messages from props depending on exception type. Collect all the messages into one response.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I avoided to create a custom validator just for this purpose. And as far as I see, it seems impossible with the current annotations e.g. `@NotBlank`, right?

Comment: @devx
Found this https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-message-interpolation

4 paragraph. You can use Expression Language in message parameter to customize it. 
E.g. `@Size(max = 10, message = "{comment.size.message}")` and place in ValidationMessages.properties file something like this: `comment.size.message=The license plate '${validatedValue}' must be between {min} and {max} characters long`

Comment: But it does not give the field name, instead gives field value. Right?

Comment: 9.2.1 it looks like u can implement MessageInterpolator. Or extend hibernate Interpolator  implementation where u can retrieve filed name from context and format your message

Comment: Could you please post an example for that implementation? You can modify my implementation if it is possible?